# SQL Like query last match

Tags: sql

I've a database that has a name field. (i.e Firstname M. Lastname or just Firstname Lastname).
Trying to filter by lastname.
How can I do a query to find the last space?

Something like
select * from person where name like "% a%" (but the space is the last space)

Thanks,
Tee

Comment: I don't think you can just with LIKE. What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If using some version of Microsoft SQL Server, you could `reverse()` the string, and then use `charindex()` to find the first space.

Answer (score 0):

If this is mySQL, you can consider using the [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function (with `count = -1`).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN [Name] LIKE '% [^ ]%'
            THEN SUBSTRING([Name], 
                           LEN([Name]) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE([Name])) + 1, 
                           8000)
            ELSE [Name]
       END AS [LastName]
FROM [Customers]
```